# How can I use R stringr to leave only the gene name?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, stringr

I have a large spreadsheet with 3200 observations that has a list of genes in a column. The column however has a bunch of junk that I don't need (example below). How can I use stringr to remove the unnecessary junk and leave only the gene name?

Example: The gene names are TEM-126 and ykkD.

```
gb|AY628199|+|203-1064|ARO:3000988|TEM-126
gb|AL009126|+|1376854-1377172|ARO:3003064|ykkD
```

Comment: It is not clear to me if this string correspond to two different rows in a column or if it represents a single string.

The pattern of where the gene names appear is consistent or it doesn't have a pattern at all?

Comment: `gsub(".*ARO:\\d+\\|(.*)$", "\\1", s)`

Comment: If you're reading the spreadsheet into R you can use `|` as the separator and it will give you 6 columns. Then select the 6th column.

Answer (score 1):

If your gene names are always at the tail of your strings, you can try the code below

```
> gsub(".*\\|","",v)
[1] "TEM-126" "ykkD"
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c("gb|AY628199|+|203-1064|ARO:3000988|TEM-126",
       "gb|AL009126|+|1376854-1377172|ARO:3003064|ykkD")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
str_split_fixed(genes, '\\|', n = 6)[, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have those names in a column and it seems that the gene name is the last "word", you could easily do that using just two packages from [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Text,
   "gb|AY628199|+|203-1064|ARO:3000988|TEM-126",
   "gb|AL009126|+|1376854-1377172|ARO:3003064|ykkD"
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(gene = word(Text, start = -1, end = -1, sep = "\\|"))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Text                                           gene   
#>   <chr>                                          <chr>  
#> 1 gb|AY628199|+|203-1064|ARO:3000988|TEM-126     TEM-126
#> 2 gb|AL009126|+|1376854-1377172|ARO:3003064|ykkD ykkD
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector `genevec` of gene names, you can vectorise the function:

```
stringr::str_split(pattern="\\|", string=genevec, simplify=T)[,6]
```